# The Gson.jar do not refer to Maven Dependency, even through it has being managed by spring-boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gson

First of all, the project built in Spring-boot. Then I want to use gson, so I added dependency to pom.xml. but a warning occurred:

```
The managed version is 2.8.0 The artifact is managed in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.3.RELEASE
```

I click it ,and find spring-boot do have managed:[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyald.png)
BUT, if I remove the dependency declare by myself, gson.jar is gone. I CANNOT use gson...
so how can I use the gson which managed by spring-boot dependency?

Comment: Apparently, you are using some kind of IDE, which tries to resolve somethings for you. You can always use mvn dependency:list or mvn dependency:tree on the command line to see what is included and why. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse on mac, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

yes spring boot provides Gson dependency and you can directly use it without defining explicitly. You SHOULD not face any problem while accessing gson without defining in dependency. I have tried by myself and able to use it. Try updating project (i.e if you are using eclipse right click on project > Maven > Update project.. > click on force update of snapshot/release).

Comment: I tried , but it didnt work. I can not find gson.jar in the maven dependency...I am using eclipse on mac

Comment: can you please share your pom.xml ?

Comment: `<groupId>muyi</groupId>
  <artifactId>weather</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
 <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>`